# If I'm already above the clouds -- how much higher can I go?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

What Z-Level are the clouds at?

I've found the perfect place to build my minecraft base

[image]

Right there, in the orange circle. But I can't help but notice. That's pretty damn high. I know minecraft has a max z-level limit, and if my base-to-be is situated above the clouds, I must be getting close to the top.

I'm still trying to fix my portal system so that I can consistently get up there (Freakin' portals, how do they work?) and until that's fixed (or I laboriously carve stairs back up to the top) I can't test for myself.

So if I'm already above the clouds -- how much higher can I go?

Comment: The inexact answer is, not much higher (a few blocks).  But I'm sure someone will come along with a more precise measurement.

Comment: Y is the axis height is measured in not Z

Comment: It might be easier to just get a pile of like sand and just jump placing blocks below you.  Once you can no longer jump any higher you know you have reached the top.  Build a second stack of sand and dig your way down and count blocks.

Comment: @Ronan I'm not sure where you got that idea.  Z is height.

Comment: @StrixVaria -- well he's true -- for 2 dimensions, anyway. As minecraft is 3d, however, you have the right of it.

Comment: @StrixVaria [Ahem](http://www.knupps.net/xyz-coordinates.png)

Comment: @Ronan Forman -- http://www.flashandmath.com/advanced/simple3d/pic1c.jpg

Comment: @Ronan Anyone can make a pretty graph.  That doesn't make it correct.

Comment: I didnt make that graph and have you even checked to see if you right before arguing?

Comment: @StrixVaria (and @Raven) in computer graphics Y usually represents the vertical axis (up and down the screen), X left and right and Z in and out the screen. However, some systems do use the coordinate system you link to. Given that positive values can be taken in either direction you can get a *lot* of variation. I used to work in 3D graphics and had to translate data from one modelling system to another and it was a *pain* as you had to check what coordinate system the source and target systems used and account for it.

Comment: @ChrisF Fair enough.  Thanks for the clarification :)

Comment: Ronan is right: http://www.minecraftwiki.net/wiki/Coordinates

Comment: OUTDATED because of anvil.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As of [1.2.1](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Version_history#1.2.1), the build limit doubled from 128 to 256, while cloud height appears to not have moved. This means you actually have *more* room to build *above* the clouds (about 128) than you do between sea level and the clouds (about 64).

---

As of [Beta 1.8](http://mcupdate.tumblr.com/post/10199253666/minecraft-beta-1-8), clouds now appear [above the build limit](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Clouds). Notch also claims to have made the level height more consistent throughout the code, which leads me to assume that the <del>clouds will always remain above the build limit regardless of that actual number</del>.

I tested this by building the tallest possible pillar in creative mode. Standing on top of it (picture 1) puts your head just above the clouds. Flying beside it (picture 2) confirms that the clouds are above the build limit. Standing on a 1 meter shorter pillar puts the clouds just above your head, meaning that the clouds are about 1.5 meters above the build limit.

[image: Standing on the height cap.]
[image: Flying beneath the clouds.]

Comment: I originally added a comment noting this fact to Badp's answer. Given that he seems disinclined to edit it, however, I may as well switch the accepted answer away from the outdated one.

Comment: @RavenDreamer - Ah! I had looked for updated answers, but missed your comment. I reckon there are lot of outdated Minecraft questions out there after the last few big releases..

Comment: Well, I think the problem was mine - I chose to add a comment to an answer already well-saturated with comments :P

Comment: @RavenDreamer - "Well-saturated" is a good term for posts which have begun hiding comments. I think I'll steal that for later use!

Comment: Heh, the question was asked years ago when Minecraft was in alpha, and the accepted answer is from the "Adventure Update", Beta 1.8

Answer (score 17):

The clouds are at height 49-46 above sea level. That gives you a 15 meters' room above the clouds.

Comment: Meter meaning blocks?

Comment: Yes. One block is high 1 meter.

Comment: Do you have a source for the clouds info?

Comment: @Raven, not really. I merely took my pile of gravel and built all the way up then down. I took a video of the process, but it doesn't look exciting at all.

Comment: I have finally been able to verify this for myself. I think your cloud range might be off a bit (I found the top of a cloud at +47, and I'm pretty sure this cloud was at least 5 blocks tall), but after measuring with some wood blocks, my portal (as seen in the picture) is 14 levels below the maximum block height.

Comment: As of the 1.8 prerelease, clouds are at the ceiling of the world.

Answer (score 4):

You can put blocks 64 metres (blocks) above sea level. [Source](http://uk.gamespot.com/pc/adventure/minecraft/show_msgs.php?topic_id=m-1-56837045&pid=606524). I don't know how high clouds are though

Comment: The z-axis goes up to 127, sea level is at 64. Clouds are commonly around 45-50 ASL, or 109-114.

Answer (score 2):

I'm in the same situation. There is plenty of height for a few floors above the clouds. I will recommend against building complex structures AT cloud level, because having your viewpoint enter and exit the clouds as you walk around is very disorienting and blocks your view a lot.

Also, have you considered a ladder for going up and down, or a boosted minecart track? And a waterfall is always the easiest fast way down.

Comment: A pool of water 3 deep works wonders. :)

Comment: Yup.  My rapid descent system is a single water source block placed 3 squares above the floor and then three signs (the fourth side is solid) placed to keep the water from spilling out.  Plunge and walk away.

Answer (score 1):

The world generates (from the first layer of bedrock) 128 blocks all the way to the sky, 64 blocks above sea level. In 1.8 clouds are above the build limit of 128.