# Can I get struck by lightning in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I wasn't able to find this post on here, but I am extremely curious if I need to be worried about instantly getting fried when working on an outdoor project.

Can I get struck by lightning during a storm in Minecraft?  If so, will it kill me?

Comment: Since you're building it may be worth looking at [How to lightning-proof a structure?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/21199/how-to-lightning-proof-a-structure)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, you can be struck by lightning: Being struck by lightning or standing near a lightning strike deals two and a half hearts of damage, not including damage from the fire. [Source](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Lightning)

Since it doesn't deal too much damage you should survive it as long as you aren't damaged too much. Btw. beware of supercharged creepers, they deal a lot of damage.

Also you don't have to worry about your constructs going up in flames because of a lightning since rain puts fire out.

Answer (score 2):

There is a very small possibility that you can be struck by lightning. Other mobs can also be struck, and it has varying effect, for example:

- If a pig gets hit by lightning it will turn into a Zombie Pigman.
- If lightning strikes a creeper it will become supercharged and be even more deadly.

Answer (score -10):

No, it wont kill you, as *Zero stack* said. It only deals 2 hearts of damage, and the rain will put it out.

But now in the upgrade of 2013, the damage of lightning is now 3 hearts, and may destroy some items in your inventory.

I've also learned from experience that when you have an item such as

- *Anvil*
- *Iron bars*
- *End portal*
- *Nether portal*
- *Mine tracks*
- *Mine carts*
- *Iron*
- *Iron armor*

You'll get struck more often, and not only that, if you are wearing a complete set of ***Iron Armor*** you'll instead take 5 hearts, not 3.

One last thing, if you are wearing ***Diamond Armor***(Full) and get struck by lighting, your armour will have a new enchantment which is called ***Armour of Gods***.  In a nut shell...   It is no longer ***Diamond Armor***, it's godlike armor.  As it will have 2 more bars of full armor, (And each stat, and enchantment will multiply by 10x) and will be 10x more effective, typically for each stat, for example, *Blast protection 10x*, *Feather falling 10x*, *Protection 10x*, *Fire protection 10x*, etc.

Well I hope this helps

Comment: Do you have a source for all this? The wiki disagrees, but then it's often slightly behind the updates.

Comment: I have checked the code, and the odds of getting struck by lightning is _entirely_ random, and has _nothing_ to do with your inventory, or the type of block that the lightning strikes at.

Comment: And as for the _Armour of the Gods_, you must be playing with some sort of mod, because there is NOTHING of the sort anywhere in the game code, and I have never seen such armor appear in any let's plays.

Comment: Downvoted for possible data forging.